# How to display the category wise news in tabs ?? I am using news manager plugin for adding news?

Tags: wordpress

Till now i have listed the category in tabs. But did not get the news and its description under the category. And in database the news are treated as post's.
And I am using the **jquery tabs for displaying news**..

MY CODE:---

```
<?php
/* 
Template Name: tabbing
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="tab">
<?php
//list terms in a given taxonomy (useful as a widget for twentyten)
$taxonomy = 'news-category';
$tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy);

?>


 <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
   <?php  $counter = 0;   foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) { ?>
      <li role="presentation" class="post-<?php  ?> <?=($counter == 1) ? 'active' : ''?>"><a href="#post-<?php ; ?>" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $tax_term->name; ?></a></li>

   <?php   $counter++; } //exit; ?> 
 </ul>

/* Right all description is displaying but not according to the category... */
    <div class="tab-content">
        <?php
        $counter = 0;
        $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'news', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
            $counter++;
        ?>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane <?=($counter == 1) ? 'active' : ''?>" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php the_content();?></div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
</div>  


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```